# Scroll up for each article

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade

I have a list of articles on my page, and starting with the second article there should be a scroll up button. The question is how to do it correctly. Here is my code

**php.blade**

```
<div class="blog-list">
    @foreach($articles as $article)
        <div class="blog-article @foreach ($article->blog_categories as $blog_category) category_{{ $blog_category->id }} @endforeach">
            <picture>
                <source srcset="{{ $article->main_image }}">
                <img class="article_image" srcset="{{ $article->main_image }}" alt="">
            </picture>

            <div class="container">

                //Scroll up
                <div class="top-button-blog-wrapper">
                    <div id="scrollTopButtonBlog" class="top-button-blog">
                        <div class="top-button-blog_text">To top</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

           <h2 class="blog-article__title">{{ $article->title }}</h2>
           <span>{{ date('d F Y', strtotime($article->published_at)) }}</span>

        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**js**

```
//Scroll up
const scrollTopButtonBlog = document.getElementById('scrollTopButtonBlog');
scrollTopButtonBlog.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });
});
```

Now my code adds a scroll button for each new blog, but it works only for the first one, maybe this `Scroll up` code should not be added to the article itself, but separately and simply fixed in the right place? What is the best way to proceed here?

Comment: Yep, the best way is to have a button that's hidden by default. You can then listen for the [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) event and then if the scroll is past a certain point, render the button

Comment: @MartinTavernier And you have not accidentally seen similar examples of where exactly there is hiding and appearing in the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how I would do it

```js
const scrollTopButton = document.getElementById("scrollTopButton");
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if(window.scrollY > 100) {
    // Removing inline style to reset the display property to what's set in stylesheet
    scrollTopButton.style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    // Hiding the button with inline style
    scrollTopButton.style.opacity = "0";
  }
});
scrollTopButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });
});
```

```css
#scrollable {
  overflow:auto;
}
#firstDiv {
  background-color: green;
  height: 1500px;
}
#scrollTopButton {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable">
  <div id="firstDiv"></div>
  <div id="scrollTopButton" style="opacity: 0">ScrollTop</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, with an event listener on the scroll, you can know when the user scroll and how many pixel have been scroll by now. And in function of this, you can show/hide the button

Comment: I did the same on my page, it appears when scrolling, but not clickable at all, and backward scrolling up does not work accordingly. Does it even make a difference where it will be on the page? I have this code right after blog-list

Comment: @Kim2000 Well, it souldn't make a difference. Could you check if the event listener is correctly added and if there is something in front of the button ? Or could you make a jsFiddle/share a little bit more of your code so that I can help you more precisly ?

Comment: I was able to figure it out further, thanks a lot for the help)